# SVG: a circle of Circles

Tags: javascript, html, svg

So to explain simply i've this SVG circle element as so:

```
var circle = function(cx,cy,r) {
var svgCircle = document.createElementNS(NS,"circle");
    svgCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx", cx);
    svgCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy", cy);
    svgCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"r", r);
return svgCircle;
```

}

it does the job it needs todo however i now need to create an abitrary amount of circles I.E 7, and position each so that they look like the outline of a circle.

so a circle made up of circles.

I just can't seem to understand how it works. Also an explanation or some guidance would go a long way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This will draw satellite circles around a center-point

The key is to convert your calculated **polar** (angle,radius) coordinates to **cartesian** (x,y). See the added function `polarToCartesian()` in the example below:

```
<svg id="my_svg" height="400" width="400"></svg>

<script type="text/javascript">

function drawCircle(cx,cy,r){

    var svgCircle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',"circle");
        svgCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx", cx);
        svgCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy", cy);
        svgCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"r", r);
        svgCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke",'blue')
        svgCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill",'transparent')
    return svgCircle;

}

function polarToCartesian(center_x, center_y, radius, angle_in_degrees) {
    var return_value = {}
    var angle_in_radians =  angle_in_degrees * Math.PI / 180.0;
        return_value.x =    center_x + radius * Math.cos(angle_in_radians);
        return_value.y =    center_y + radius * Math.sin(angle_in_radians);
    return return_value;
}

/*  ==============================
    Loop to Draw Satellite circles
    ==============================  */

//  The center is the same for all circles
var cx = 200
var cy = 200

var radius_of_satellites_from_center = 100
var radius_of_small_circles = 10
var number_of_satellite_circles = 7

//  The angle increments for each circle drawn
for(var n=0; n<number_of_satellite_circles; n++){

    //  Find how many degrees separate each circle
    var degrees_of_separation = 360/number_of_satellite_circles

    var angle_as_degrees = degrees_of_separation * n

    var coordinates = polarToCartesian(cx, cy, radius_of_satellites_from_center, angle_as_degrees)

    document.getElementById('my_svg').appendChild( drawCircle(coordinates.x,coordinates.y,radius_of_small_circles) )

}

</script>
```

Comment: In relation to this, i'm just wondering how i'd do a semi-circle (arc) of circles instead of an entire circle?

Answer (score 1):

### This will draw concentric circles:

```
<svg id="my_svg" height="400" width="400"></svg>

<script type="text/javascript">

function drawCircle(cx,cy,r){

    var svgCircle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',"circle");
        svgCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx", cx);
        svgCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy", cy);
        svgCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"r", r);
        svgCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke",'blue')
        svgCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill",'transparent')
    return svgCircle;

}

/*  ===============================
    Loop to Draw concentric circles
    =============================== */

//  The center is the same for all circles
var cx = 200
var cy = 200

//  More settings you can change
var starting_radius = 50
var number_of_circles = 7
var gap_between_circles = 3

//  The radius increments for each circle drawn
for(var n=number_of_circles; n>0; n--){
    var radius =    starting_radius + n * gap_between_circles
    document.getElementById('my_svg').appendChild( drawCircle(cx,cy,radius) )
}

</script>
```

Comment: Ah i see that's incredibly helpful! However i ramble most times. Esstianlly what i need is "little" circles going around the edge of the big circle with something like a gap of 10px each.

Comment: Got it.  See updated answer.  You can define your `gap_between_circles `, the `starting_radius` of the inner-most circle, and the `number_of_circles ` to draw.

Comment: Again i really appreciate this (i know this will come in handy later) haha, but what i mean is this - https://jsfiddle.net/tv4v8L36/.  Those little circles need to go around in a circle ^_^.

Comment: Got it. See my other answer for 'satellite' circles.

Comment: omfg wow!  So the issue is that the standard SVG circle is polar based co-ords?

Comment: Yup, `SVG` is all 'cartesian (x,y)' so when you're doing something like this example, the placement of each satellite is thought of as 'polar (360 degrees, radius)'.  So we have to convert those polar coordinates back to (x,y) cartesian values to make sense of it for our `circle(cx,cy,r)` drawing function.

Comment: Good question topic!  I would try to make the question a little clearer in expressing what you're looking for.  In my first answer I misunderstood the question. Maybe add a picture to your question of your desired SVG output. I would definitely upvote the question if it was a little clearer or had a small picture of your desired end result.  Also, as a side note, It was very helpful that you provided some of your existing code in the question as a starting point.

Comment: FactoryAidan, this makes things a whole lot clerer! thank you very much for the help you've provided! I'll take your suggestions onboard for next time i ask a question, and i'll try to be a little clearer! Again thank you for all your help!